# how to parse a file with tab separated data in ech line in java

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist

I have a text file with tab separated data like this:

```
0   fashioned   0.01
0   hard    0.01
0   taking  0.01
0   cool    0.01
0   conversation    0.01
0   biz 0.01
0   jobs    0.01
0   invest  0.01
1   loving  48.01
1   networks    0.01
1   campaigns   0.01
1   raise   0.01
1   competition 0.01
1   kitten  0.01
1   slashed 0.01
1   planned 0.01
```

I need to store in format:
    0,<0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01>
    1,<48.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01>
    How can this be done? I have tried this code but its not giving appropriate output.

```
 public void wordArray() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {        

        ArrayList<Integer> topic = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Double> val = new ArrayList<Double>();

        String s,tweet[] = null, d[];
        int us = -1;
        double max = 0;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/home/lenovo/abc/words.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        list1=new ArrayList<Double>();

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            us++;
            d = s.split("\t");
            topic.add(Integer.parseInt(d[0]));

            if(us==0){
                list1.add(Double.parseDouble(d[2]));
                maxp.put(topic.get(us),list1);
            }
            else{
               maxp.put(Integer.parseInt(d[0]),list1=new ArrayList<Double>());
               list1.add(Double.parseDouble(d[2]));
            }
```

I want to create a new list for different value of first column and add to map.

Comment: do you have problems with some specific issue with your code?

Comment: consider creating a `Map`, where the `key` will be the number from line beginning, and the `value` is formed as a list of values

Comment: @joval : can u write a piece of code so that i can understand bettr

Comment: @eis i dont know whether i did correcr code or not..i am not grtting the desired output

Answer (score 4):

I like libs. Try jackson, commons.collection - you get real POJOS

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap;

public class Jackson {

    private static final String data = "0\tFirst name\t10\t1.23\n"
            + "1\tSecond name\t23\t\n"
            + "0\tThird name\t30\t1.87";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Data.class)
                .withoutHeader()
                .withColumnSeparator('\t')
                .withLineSeparator("\n");
        Iterator<Data> result = mapper.reader(Data.class).withSchema(schema).readValues(data);
        MultiValueMap map = new MultiValueMap();
        while (result.hasNext()) {
            Data d = result.next();
            map.put(d.getIndex(), d);
            System.out.println(d);
        }
        //
        // Here is your map
        //
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    public static class Data implements Serializable {

        private int index;
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private Double size;

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public void setIndex(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public Double getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void setSize(Double size) {
            this.size = size;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", size=" + size + '}';
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it looks overly complicated and unreadable.

But you can turn it around by creating an object and using a map.

e.g. you can create a object to represent a record -

```
class Record {
    private final Integer topic;
    private final String word;
    private final Double value;

    public Record(Integer topic, String word, Double value) {   
        this.topic = topic;
        this.word = word;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Record valueOf(String recordLine) {
        String[] fields = recordLine.split("\\s+");
        return new Record(
            Integer.valueOf(fields[0]), 
            fields[1], 
            Double.valueOf(fields[2])
        );
    }

    public Integer getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And then declare a map as follows -

```
Map<Integer, List<Record>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Record>>();
```

And then populate the map -

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Record currRec = Record.valueOf(line);
    List<Record> currList = map.get(currRec.getTopic());
    if(currList == null) {
        currList = new ArrayList<Record>();
        map.put(currRec.getTopic(), currList);
    }
    currList.add(currRec);
```

Now you have records grouped by topics.

Comment: what is this getTopic() function?

Comment: It's a getter in the `Record` class, look at the update.

Comment: with this code also not getting correct output..its displays some garbage values.